# Google Maps Geolocation API or Directions API

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I use the Google Maps Geolocation API for indoor positioning and detecting not just lat/long but also elevation. Alternatively is there a way for the Directions API to tell me if indoor directions were completed?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this document [Indoor maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps), you can use Google Maps API. At high zoom levels, the map will show floor plans for indoor spaces such as airports, shopping malls, large retail stores, and transit stations. These floor plans, called indoor maps, are displayed for the 'normal' and `satellite` map types **(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL and GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)**. They are automatically enabled when the user zooms in, and they fade away when the map is zoomed out.

Indoor maps (floor plans) are available in [select locations](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1685827). If floor plan data is not available for a building that you would like to highlight in your application, you can:

Add [floor plans](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/) to Google Maps directly. This will make your floor plans available to all users of Google Maps.
Display a floor plan as a [ground overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay) or [tile overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) on your map. This will enable only users of your application to view your floor plans.

If you have added a MapFragment (or MapView) programmatically, then you can configure its initial state by passing in a GoogleMapOptions object with your options specified. The options available to you are exactly the same as those available via XML. You can create a GoogleMapOptions object like this:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();

options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
.compassEnabled(false)
.rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
.tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
```

The Google Maps Elevation API provides elevation data for all locations on the surface of the earth, including depth locations on the ocean floor (which return negative values). Check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start